# Sunrise show Image Sunset show different one

Tags: php

I have this code that gets the time for sunrise and sunset time for today's date.

THE CODE IS:

```
<?php
function miltoampm($hour) {   
    $mins = substr($hour,-2);
    $ampm = ($hour >=12 && $hour <24) ? "PM" : "AM";   
    $newhour = ($hour % 12 === 0) ? 12 : $hour % 12;   
    return $newhour . ':' . $mins . " " . $ampm;   
}   


//Calculate the sunrise and sunset time
//Latitude: 41.81
//Longitude: -87.68
//Zenith ~= 90
//offset: -5 GMT is Chicago
$sunriseTime = (date_sunrise(time(),SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING,41.8119,-87.6873,90,-5)); //Sunrise Time
$sunsetTime = (date_sunset(time(),SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING,41.8119,-87.6873,90,-5)); //Sunset Time
?>
```

Now I would like to do this but I don't really know how:

```
If current time is anywhere from $sunrise and less then $sunset then
    $Img = "sun.png";
else
    $Img = "noon.png";
end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `date_sunrise` return format to be `SUNFUNCS_RET_TIMESTAMP` instead of `SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING` so you can compare it to the current timestamp:

```
$sunriseTime = date_sunrise( time(), SUNFUNCS_RET_TIMESTAMP, 41.8119, -87.6873, 90, -5 );
$sunsetTime  = date_sunset(  time(), SUNFUNCS_RET_TIMESTAMP, 41.8119, -87.6873, 90, -5 );
```

...then do the **comparison**:

```
$img = time() > $sunriseTime && time() < $sunsetTime ? 'sun.png' : 'moon.png';
```

...then show your **resulting image**:

```
echo '<img src="' . $img . '" />';
```

You can then print out the *sunrise* and *sunset* times:

```
echo 'Sunrise: ' . strftime("%r", $sunriseTime) . '<br/>';
echo 'Sunset: ' . strftime("%r", $sunsetTime);
```

Comment: Sweet, works great but how do I convert the $sunsetTime or $sunriseTime (output eg: '1376651074') into AM/PM format ? Because I want to tell the visitors when the sun will be out and when it will set. THANKS for the help again:)

Comment: It's a timestamp, so you can just pass it along to `strftime`. Something like `strftime("%r", $sunsetTime)` - see [here for a full reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? This checks if currentTime is between sunrise and sunset.

```
<?php
    if(currentTime >= sunrise && currentTime <= sunset){
      echo "sunrise";
    }
    else {
      echo "sunset";
    }
?>
```